# AAD users lose access to database after import

Tags: sql-server, users, active-directory, contained-database

I googled for the last few days but I got a bit confused and I do not know how to proceed further. Also, I'm not a DBA and I was just faced with this situation for the first time.
Using sqlpackage.exe I'm exporting a bacpac from a PRD DB and import it on another server to refresh the lower environments. The original database is contained. After I'm importing the new database, the contained database users and the AAD external ones lose access to the new database.
I'm fixing the contained database user by updating its password with

```
ALTER USER [RandomUser] WITH PASSWORD='randomPassword'
```

but I am not sure what to do with the AAD users. They have an external user created for them (the aad users are placed inside a group). So far my option is to drop the said user and recreate it

```
CREATE USER [sthRandom] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

but in order to do this, you have to be connected with an AAD user

```
Principal 'sthRandom' could not be created. Only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users.
```

I have to automate this whole process so I could use a service principal like [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/azure-ad-service-principal-authentication-to-sql-db-code-sample/ba-p/481467). I'm creating the service principal inside all the databases, but after refresh the user won't exist anymore, or I create it in the PRD database too, but I can not use it to login anymore.

What other options do I have? Thanks

Comment: I've never worked with AAD users, but you might try to just [map those users to logins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-correct-a-mismatched-sid) that exist on the lower environments instead of deleting and creating new ones. Have you tried it?

Comment: AAD logins are only available on Managed Instance.

Comment: Yes, they do not have logins. What else I can do? I need this AAD account to have access to every database, even after it was restored. I was thinking to add it into an AAD group and put that group as an administrator on the server.  Thanks